# Slider button click in selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My issue is the following :

I am training to retrieve the information on this website https://www.cetelem.es/.

I want to do several things:

- Click on the two slide buttons to change the information.
- Retrieve the information following the change of the sliding buttons
- Put a condition, only retrieve information when tin and tae change.

I tried with the following code on google colab :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.cetelem.es/"

webdriver.get(url)
webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("bar-slider importe").send_keys("20.000")
webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("bar-slider messes").send_keys("30")
webdriver.save_screenshot('sreenshot.png')
print(webdriver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV9nn.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV9nn.png)

If you have the solution, can you explain my mistake? Because I'm a real beginner in scraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not ideal but you could use the +/- buttons to adjust slider until target hit. This is an example for the top slider. You should also restrict the bounds of the target to lower of 4.000 € and upper of 60.000 €.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.cetelem.es/"

webdriver.get(url)
targetSliderStep = 22.700
targetSliderStep = round(targetSliderStep  * 2) / 2  # to ensure is units covered by clicking
print('target: ' + "{0:.3f}".format(targetSliderStep))
actualSliderStep = float(webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-step-value').text.replace(' €',''))

if actualSliderStep < targetSliderStep:
    while float(webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-step-value').text.replace(' €','')) < targetSliderStep:
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#slider-step .up-button").click()
elif actualSliderStep > targetSliderStep:
    while float(webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-step-value').text.replace(' €','')) > targetSliderStep:
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#slider-step .down-button").click()
print('actual: ' + webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-step-value').text.replace(' €',''))
```

---

**To answer your other questions:**

**Other slider:**

Use same logic for other slider (and perhaps add in bounds of 12-96):

```
targetTimeStep = 22.700
targetTimeStep = round(int(targetTimeStep))  # to ensure is units covered by clicking
print('target: ' + str(targetTimeStep))
actualTimeStep = int(webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-time-step-value').text)

if actualTimeStep < targetTimeStep:
    while int(webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-time-step-value').text) < targetTimeStep:
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#slider-time-step .up-button").click()
elif actualTimeStep > targetTimeStep:
    while int(webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-time-step-value').text) > targetTimeStep:
        webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#slider-time-step .down-button").click()
print('actual: ' + webdriver.find_element_by_id('slider-time-step-value').text)
```

---

**Select projects:**

You can get all the longer list of projects by clicking the left side menu bars and then targeting the project links by the href attribute value substrings.

```
webdriver.find_element_by_id('showLeft').click()
webdriver.find_element_by_id('layout_6').click()
projects = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[href*='prestamos/prestamo-']")
print(len(projects))
```

---

**CSS selectors:**

I use CSS selectors through out as modern browsers are optimized for CSS.

The following, for example,

```
#slider-step .up-button
```

Is a parent element with id (`#`) `slider-step` in descendant combination with an element/elements with class (`.`) `up-button`. The `#` is an [id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors), the `.` a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and the `" "` is a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) i.e. select children with this class that have a parent with that id.

You want to use id selectors where possible then class selectors as faster selectors.

If you right click inspect element on the `+` button, for example, for the top slider you will see the following HTML:

[image]

You can clearly see the parent id and the child class for the `+` .

If you want to practice css selectors the following [link](https://flukeout.github.io/) is fun and you can read up on selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have some questions for you:

How could I click to advance Meses para devolverlo, and click on Selecciona tu proyecto to change projects?

How did you find # slider-step .up-button? How if I change my website, I could adapt.

Last question, how can I find documentation to better understand and adapt to all websites?

Thank you so much.

Comment: you should normally ask follow up questions as new questions but hopefully the above will help.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're genius !

Comment: Not really. There are some real web gurus in this tag but am happy to help.

Comment: Last question: If I want to select Viajes for example as a project, how would I do?

Comment: webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href$='prestamo-viajes']").click()

Comment: basically they each have an href which ends with the name e.g. webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href$='prestamo-estudios']").click()

Comment: I have the following error: ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.98,platform=Linux 4.14.79+ x86_64)

Comment: you need to click on the dropdown to expose I suspect.

Comment: however the url constructs are all the same so you can just .get(newURL)

Comment: Okay, I'll do that

Comment: When I run the code, I do not get the exact duration https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTO0t.png

Comment: that is odd. Have you verified with looking at the page at the same time? It ran fine for me but I will have a run of it again and see if I have missed something.

Comment: Hello @QHarr Have you had time to see the duration and click on the project?

Comment: Yes, tomorrow will be fine. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies for delay. I made a typo (my bad). The bottom slider should reference targetTimeStep  throughout in the while loop. I forgot to change from the code I copied from top slider. Sorry! Edited now.

Comment: That's ok. Sorry it took so long to get round to reviewing it. Appreciate your patience.