# Selenium python slider bouton Element Not Visible Exception

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to write to a parser to click a button on a website and I can not click two of the buttons.

I would like to click on "Elija el imports a financiar" and "Elija la mensualidad"

Here's the html: https://www.cofidis.es/es/creditos-prestamos/prestamo-personal.html

python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://www.cofidis.es/es/creditos-prestamos/prestamo-personal.html"

webdriver.get(url)
targetSliderStep = 6.000
targetSliderStep = round(targetSliderStep  * 2) / 2  # to ensure is units covered by clicking
print('target: ' + "{0:.3f}".format(targetSliderStep))
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btncerrar"]').click()
actualSliderStep = float(webdriver.find_element_by_id('I2:simuPanel.O').text.replace(' €',''))
print(actualSliderStep)
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.mensMoreId"]').click()
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.mensLessId"]').click()
print(actualSliderStep)

webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.mensMoreId"]').click()
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.mensLessId"]').click()

print(webdriver.find_element_by_id('I2:simuPanel.O7').text)
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.durMoreId"]').click()
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.durLessId"]').click()
print(webdriver.find_element_by_id('I2:simuPanel.O7').text)
```

I am getting this error.

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: import sleep and put between clicks time.sleep(1) , and check if its still doing the same problem, if it doesnt help, scroll to the buttom of the website before you start using elements ( also put wait after driver.get()

Comment: All right, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your Xpath is correct.But it is not interact able.
Please try the actionchain it should work. The code will work with headless when you add this below chrome options as well.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=2560x1440')
```

Instead of this

```
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.mensMoreId"]').click()
```

Please Try

```
 el=webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="I2:simuPanel.amountMoreId"]')
   ActionChains(webdriver).move_to_element(el).click(el).perform()
```

In that way change all 4 slide button click option.Let me know if that works.

Comment: When I try, there is no mistake. But the amount does not change.

Comment: I have updated the answer this should definitely work

Comment: No error, but amount does not change. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KhLy.png

Comment: Strange. It is changing on my laptop.Can you put some delay and remove the the headless option for testing.For me its showing 12.075 after 3 times click on the same button.

Comment: Sorry mate its not changing with headless.Let me check whats wrong.It is working without headless.

Comment: My code will work fine if you add this one in ur head less options. ```chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=2560x1440')``` Try that.I have tested just now.

Comment: @TiffanyZucman : Have you tried the last updated answer.Please let me know once you try.

Comment: It is done. I have a problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638518/slider-button-click-in-selenium-python/54639742?noredirect=1#comment96089064_54639742, do you have time to look?

Comment: The problem with the link is that I can not move the duration and select an object.

Comment: Sorry mate I am away from work.will defianately look later.